# Can I cast from Task<ObservableCollection<Class>> to ObservableCollection<Class>?

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await

I have a working Async method (web scrape) that works, but cannot update a View.
I can see the INotifyPropertyChanged event is not firing.

In my constructor I call the async method like so:

```
Task<ObservableCollection<Team>> TeamRows2 = Scrape();
```

My Scrape method returns:

```
ObservableCollection<Team> rows
```

By this method signature:

```
private async Task<ObservableCollection<Team>> Scrape()
ObservableCollection<Team> rows = new ObservableCollection<Team>();
// do Async work
return rows;
```

I can see rows get filled with the Async web obtained data.

But the call to Scrape does not seem to load TeamRows2 with rows when it returns.

Do I need to cast from plain ObservableCollection from Task somehow for that to work?

Thanks

Comment: Cast? No, no, no, no... What you want is the [Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx). Edit: I think you would be better without `async`.

Comment: you need to wait for the task to finish.  Either `await` or calling `.Result` on the task

Comment: Do **not** use Task.Result. Read the great blog of [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/) why you should not do that

Comment: I have to use async / await, as I am using: htmlDoc = await web.LoadFromWebAsync(url);                I tied putting  Scrape().Result;     But it errors :(

Comment: My VMs have an InitializeAsync( object parameter ) method and all initialization will happen there. The constructor only takes the dependency (if any) but did not initialize any data

Comment: Doing `async` work inside the constructor is a bad design decision. You have to call `await Scrape()` in a different method which is declared `async` outside your constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments already suggested you need to wait for the task to finish. There is the method to call `Task.Result` but there are some common cases where calling this method causes a deadlock in your application and everything comes to a stop.

As a general rule you can say: Never mix `async/await` with `.Result/.Wait`.

Now your main issue is that you are working inside a constructor and need to wait for your task to complete. The solution to this issue I prefer is a static factory method.

Like so:

```
public static async Task<YourClass> CreateAsync(…)
{
   var rows = await Scrape();
   return new YourClass(rows, …);
}
```

The constructor is set to private and when you need to create a instance of the class you call the `CreateAsync` method.

This solution assumes that the `Scrape` method is static as well. But it should be anyway if you call it from the constructor (or at least it should be easy to make it `static`, since all the parameters it could receive have to be passed to the constructor.

A alternative solution is using a initialization function. This would be the solution if you can't turn the `Scape` method static. Even in this case I would suggest a factory method, to avoid exposing instances of the class that are not properly initialized.

In this case you basically need two method like this:

```
public static async Task<YourClass> CreateAsync(…)
{
   var result = new YourClass(…);
   await result.InitializeAsync();
   return result;
}

private async Task InitializeAsync()
{
   TeamRows2 = await Scrape();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nitram, it was indeed due to being done inside the constructor.